# Why EE.SE is not using new user-page?

Tags: feature-request

I have seen many stack exchange sites have modified their user-page and started using the [new user-page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/). Why EE.SE isn't?

Comment: Perhaps the designers didn't get around it yet.

Comment: The Engineering.SE has been switched to the new style, and now some things are broken.  I'd rather they just left things alone.  Things were working fine.  Stop trying to fix them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's going to be rolled out to all sites and the only reason the release has been staggered is because of changes needed to upgrade the CSS style sheets. There's a summary here of which sites have been done already and which are planned and that includes EE.SE:

[List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

If you look at the revision history you'll see progress on the remaining sites is slow but steady, but I'd expect it to be completed within [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/203972).

Comment: One a week, if that. As of August 1 2015 EE is still pending. Grr

Comment: Let's just say that all sites will have the new layout by the end of the year, just to play safe.